# How to insert a function in LLVM module

Tags: c++, llvm

I am writing an LLVM pass, where I clone some functions by calling `llvm::CloneFunction`. Now I also want to insert those functions in the module. How can I do that?

Comment: I am trying to find an LLVM API function that does that, but still am unable to find one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Create a new function with `Function::Create` or by other means. A `Function`'s constructors accept a module into which to insert the new function.
- Clone a function into that new function with [CloneFunctionInto](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/CloneFunction_8cpp_source.html), or just copy over the BBs you need.

Answer (score 0):

`CloneFunction` will automatically insert the new Function into the old Function's module. From the [doxygen](https://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm.html#aedeb89fa4ceb608d9d49bcd53ddcd2c1):

> Return a copy of the specified function and add it to that function's module.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CloneFunction and insert it into the module afterwards like so

```
  Function* duplicateFunction = CloneFunction(F, VMap,
                                              /*ModuleLevelChanges=*/false);
  F->getParent()->getFunctionList().push_back(duplicateFunction);
```

Example stolen from PartialInlining.cpp in the llvm source.